# Linux Terminal: Change cursor position after 'up arrow' key press

Tags: shell, terminal, console

I just switched one of my systems from Gentoo to Ubuntu. There is one difference between the two setups that is driving me mad, and I cannot figure out how to fix it. When I use the 'up arrow' to go to a previous command, the cursor is moved to the start of the line. In Gentoo the cursor would remain at the end of the line. I have been using this behavior for over 10 years, adapting to the new behavior will be a major pain. How does one configure this?

This happens in any terminal: urxvt, xterm, and the console before X starts. It happens in bash and zsh, and happens regardless of if I am using 'screen'. It seems to be a global setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to zsh, in debian, therefore in ubuntu too, it seems to be caused by the
global zshrc settings (/etc/zsh/zshrc).

I've been looking for this for a while. Today I wrote to the zsh-users list and got the answer:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.shells.zsh.user/12079

There's even a debian bug about it:
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=383737

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't have a Gentoo installation available I am going to guess that what you have described is almost certainly related to your [readline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readline) configuration.

A quick scan through the man page indicates this option which looks close to what you might want.

> **history-preserve-point (Off)** If set to on, the history code attempts
>   to place point at the same location on each history line retrieved
>   with previous-history or next-history.

Comment: If it happens in `zsh`, as the questioner says, it isn't `readline`.  `zsh` doesn't use `readline`.  Of course, a similar configuration difference could exist for ZLE as well.  In which case this is only half the answer.

Comment: This does indeed work for bash, which is a start. And as JdeBP Predicted, this does not work for zsh